# Automatically cycle though tooltips in GeoMap

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm having an issue using setSelection to auto-display tooltips on the loading of a map.  I'd like to eventually cycle though them but I'm unable to display even one by default.

```
  function drawRegionsMap() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
data.addRows([
    ['Australia'],
    ['Austria'],
    ['Uganda'],
    ['Ukraine'],
    ['United Kingdom'],
    ['United States'],
    ['Zambia'],
    ['Zimbabwe']
    ]);

    var options = {
      backgroundColor: '#60ABE6',
      datalessRegionColor: '#ccc',
      defaultColor: '#ff5000',
      legend: 'none',
      tooltip: { trigger: "both", isHtml: true } 
    };
   

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function(e) {
});
chart.draw(data, options);
chart.setSelection([{row:4,column:null}]);
};
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyclopsthere/4y39esva/7/)

Comment: `setSelection` needs to be called inside the ready event, or at least after it has fired. however, the ready event will not fire when using the generic / example `mapsApiKey`. need to have a valid key for it to work...

Comment: Yep that was it.. Thanks!